# Leetcode To K frequent elements

Tags: python, hashmap

I am trying to solve the problem **(Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.)** by creating a hashmap where the key is the item in the list `nums` and the pair for that value is the amount of time that item appears on the list. I loop through the list then there is an if statement that checks if that item is already a key in the dictionary, if so it will add 1 to its value, and if not, it will add it as a key and give it a value of 1. When I run the code for the list `nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`, the output is completely wrong. This is the expected output `{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}` instead I receive `{1: 5, 2: 1}`.

Here is my code:

```
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
iterations = {}

for x in nums:
    if nums[x] in iterations:
        iterations[nums[x]] += 1
    else:
        iterations[nums[x]] = 1

print(iterations)
```

Comment: `x` is not an index, `x` is an actual element (try printing it in your loop). You need to replace all `nums[x]` with just `x`

Comment: And for the future, don't assume that people know the leetcode tasks and don't expect people to search them. Include the task or a short version of it in your question.

Comment: No need to be rude. If you want to help, help if you don't then don't. (your solution didn't work)

Comment: Not trying to be rude, just explaining how StackOverflow works. And my solution works for me. You can [edit] your question to include your new code, and we'll try to help further.

Comment: @TheOdinBorson he's guiding you to write a more attracting question, so you can find an answer. Nothing rude.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych It's fine, it's sorted, thank you for the help.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv yes Im just frustrated

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected version of your code

```
 nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
 iterations = {}
  
 for x in nums:
     if x in iterations:
         iterations[x] += 1
     else:
         iterations[x] = 1

 print(iterations)
```